# Classifying the critical points a linear autonomous system of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations

I have the simple, but not so simple system:

\begin{equation}
x'=-3x+y^2+2 \\
y'=x^2-y^2
\end{equation}

and its critical points, found by solving the system by multiplying the lower by 3, and summing up, are $(x,y)=(-1,1), (1,1), (1,-1), (-1,-1)$.

I would solve this ideally by setting up the matrix

\begin{vmatrix}
-3-\lambda & 1 \\
1 & -1-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}

and solving for the determinant. But that +2 in the first equation messes things up. How do I proceed here?

Thanks!

Comment: I just have to classify the critical points.

Comment: I am not sure, but I will check and get back to this post.

Answer (score 1):

For $P(x,y)$ and $Q(x,y)$.

$P(x,y)=−3x+y^2+2$

$P(x,y)=x^2−y^2$

We have the solution by finding the Jacobian,

\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}|_{(x_1,y_1)} & \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}|_{(x_1,y_1)} \\
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}|_{(x_1,y_1)} & \frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}|_{(x_1,y_1)}
\end{vmatrix}

where we obtain:

\begin{vmatrix}
-3 & 2y \\
2x &-2y
\end{vmatrix}

Insert for each critical points:

CP : (1,1):

$DetA_1$=\begin{vmatrix}
-3 & 2\cdot 1 \\
2\cdot 1 &-2\cdot 1
\end{vmatrix}
=2.

Since 2 > 0, the system is expansive, from the critical point, and thus unstable. For a CP lesser than 0, the system is contractive, and it is therefore stable.

For CP (-1,1):  Det A= 10 > 0, Unstable.

For CP (1,-1):  Det A= -2 < 0, Stable.

For CP (-1,-1):  Det A= -10 < 0, Stable.

Then, for the second set of Critical points:

$CP_2=(x,y)\cdot 2=(1,1)\cdot 2=(2,2)$

where 2 is the constant from the inhomogenous term.

We now have:

CP : (2,2):

$Det A_2$=\begin{vmatrix}
-3 & 2\cdot 2 \\
2\cdot 2 &-2\cdot 2
\end{vmatrix}
=4.

Since 4 > 0, the system is expansive, from the critical point, and thus unstable. For a CP lesser than 0, the system is contractive, and it is therefore stable.

For CP (-2,2):  Det A_2= 38 > 0, Unstable.

For CP (2,-2):  Det A_2= 4 > 0, Unstable.

For CP (-2,-2):  Det A_2= -32 < 0, Stable.

Comment: Typo in the original problem: -3x not -3x^2

Comment: That would be related to the form $\tau^2\leq4\Delta$ ? I am not sure how to define the points further by using $\tau^2\leq4\Delta$ . I know that the determinant is $$6y-4xy$$, but where is  $\tau$ and $\Delta$ in this form?

Comment: All points are described now, but not if they are spiral or saddle. Only that they are stable unstable.

Comment: No, they are fine, the typo was only made here. Calculations were made on the paper at home, with the right form.

Comment: Thanks for all your points!

Comment: Indeed. A second set of CPs is missing.: But how do those 2's come about? It seems one only needs to multiply the CPs with the inhomogenous constant.